# Express js req.session always undefined

Tags: node.js, express

I used Express Node.js to make login page with SQL server and I want to use session. Here's my code:

```
/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var express = require('express');
var routes = require('./routes');
var user = require('./routes/user');
var admin = require('./routes/admin');
var http = require('http');
var path = require('path');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var session = require('express-session');
var async = require("async");
var edge = require('edge');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');


var app = express();

// all environments
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3030);
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');


app.use(express.favicon());
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(app.router);
app.use(require('stylus').middleware(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'assets')));
app.use(express.cookieParser());
app.use(express.session({
    cookieName: 'session',
    secret: 'dgjdjdfjfjhhytjhd',
    duration: 30 * 60 * 1000,
    sctiveDuration: 50 * 60 * 1000,
    cookie: { maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 }
}));


// development only
if ('development' == app.get('env')) {
    app.use(express.errorHandler());
}

///////////// Routs Here .......
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.send('<h5>Welcome</h5><a href="login" class="btn btn-default">Go To Login</a>');
});
app.get('/login', function(req, res) {
    res.render('login');


});
/*======================================= Post For Login & Redirect To Admin Page =====================================*/
app.post('/login', function (req, res) {
    var username = req.body.username;
    var password = req.body.password;
    var params = {
        connectionString: "Data Source=AHMAD-HOME;Initial Catalog=nodejs;Integrated Security=True",
        source: "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='"+ username+"' and password='"+ password+"'"
    };
    var getUsers = edge.func('sql', params);
    getUsers(null, function (error, result) {
        if (error) throw error;
        if (result) {
            if (result == '') {
                console.log(' Empty Data From Database');
                res.redirect('/login');
            } else {
                req.session.userid= result;
                res.redirect('admin');
            }

        } else {
            console.log('kkkkkkkkkkk');
        }

    });


    console.log('The UserName Is ' + username + ' And The Password Is : ' + password);

});
app.get('/admin',  function (req, res) {
    res.render('admin');
        console.log(req.session);// stack here
});

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function () {
    console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

I always have an `undefined` session on admin page.
I used express-session and I tried client-session before but I still the same error.

Comment: You're using `express.session` instead of just `session`. Same for `cookieParser`

Comment: i changed to (session) at past put i still have same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
app.use(**express.**session({
    cookieName: 'session',
    secret: 'dgjdjdfjfjhhytjhd',
    duration: 30 * 60 * 1000,
    sctiveDuration: 50 * 60 * 1000,
    cookie: { maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 }
}));
```

Remove the part in **s. That has been deprecated in the newest releases of Express. You have to use the middleware express-session, which you have already set up and assigned to `session`.

Comment: Recently I used This Code : `app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(session({
    cookieName: 'session',
    secret: 'dgjdjdfjfjhhytjhd',
    duration: 30 * 60 * 1000,
    activeDuration: 50 * 60 * 1000,
    cookie: { maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 }
}));
` result : Cannot Set Property 'cookieName' Of undefined

Comment: req.session.cookieName= result; when i set a session error that session is undefined  By the way i use visual studio to run my app i wander if the problem for this

Comment: Try changing `require('express-session') `to `require('cookie-session')`. You might have to `npm install cookie-session --save`. Oh, it isn't the `app.use` part throwing the error? req.session is where the session variables for each user are stored. You can't change the cookie name from there.

Comment: no the error when i set the session when data from database is true i will set session to request : req.session.user= result; i change it to user and later i used cookie-session but i have same error ersult

Comment: when i set : req.session= result; there is no error but i have undefined in admin page : console.log(req.session);